# phpMyAdmin mcrypt error on PHP7.1

Tags: phpmyadmin, localhost, mcrypt

Apache/2.4.23 (Win64) PHP/7.1.0

PhpMyAdmin: 4.6.5.2

Error Image:

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Please copy & paste the error message. That way it's much easier to read. It also makes your question complete, even if that link becomes invalid. Others can do a web search for the error message and find your question and hopefully the answers here. You could also include what you did to produce that error.

Comment: Function mcrypt_list_algorithms() is deprecated and 

mcrypt_module_open() is deprecated

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it has been abandonware for nearly a decade now. It has therefore been deprecated and will be removed from the core and into PECL in PHP 7.2. It does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt has many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution, are being maintained and is correct.

Comment: why not to move from Web GUI to something more elegant and flexible? `MySQL Workbench` or `SQLYog`. BTW desktop apps give You power to configure remote db connection through ssh tunnel.

Answer (score 3):

This was a problem regarding compatibility with such a new PHP version, technically with the [library function](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/pull/1041) that phpMyAdmin uses for various encryption functions.

[The problem was fixed](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/12800) in phpMyAdmin and will be part of the next release (which will be phpMyAdmin 4.6.6)

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to Alex's answer, the code has a typo which makes it invalid, it should look like this:

```php
public function handleError($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
    if (error_reporting() == 0 || $errno == E_DEPRECATED) { // added – $errno == E_DEPRECATED
        return;
    }
    $this->addError($errstr, $errno, $errfile, $errline, true);
}
```

Comment: worth noting - this solution works if changing setting error_reporting in php.ini does not work.

Answer (score 0):

in php.ini error_reporting = E_ALL  & ~E_DEPRECATED

If does not work, that is, the hard method – change code phpMyadmin.
set_error_handler in phpMyadmin does not take into account error_reporting.

To exclude E_DEPRECATED, in ../phpMyadmin/libraties/ErrorHandler.php

change this method

```
public function handleError($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
if (error_reporting() == 0 || $ Errno == E_DEPRECATED) { // added – $errno == E_DEPRECATED
return;
}

$this->addError($errstr, $errno, $errfile, $errline, true);
}
```

Comment: @TheReduxPL It's better to give your own answer