# phpMyAdmin with PHP 7.1.0 - TONS of deprecation warnings

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, apache2.4

I am on Windows Server 2012, using Apache 2.4 (64-bit) with PHP 7.1.0. I also have MySQL installed, and when I loaded phpMyAdmin I get a ton of warnings like the one below.

[image]

I've tried what was recommended here [PHP 7 with phpmyadmin gives lots of Deprecation Notices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37002494/php-7-with-phpmyadmin-gives-lots-of-deprecation-notices) but it did absolutely nothing. I still get all the deprecation warnings when loading phpMyAdmin. The version I downloaded is 4.6.5.2 which states that it is compatible with PHP 7.

What can I do to make these deprecation warnings go away?

Comment: According to [this q/a](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41065984/phpmyadmin-mcrypt-error-on-php7-1), it may be fixed in 4.6.6.

Comment: @aynber - can I download v 4.6.6 anywhere?  Even a DEV version?  I don't see it on the Download page

Comment: No idea. I'd suggest contacting them.

Comment: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin - tho no idea if this will help you! I'll be honest not tried running phpMyAdmin on php 7 yet! Will assume someone has though!

Comment: Could always set error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);

Comment: I removed the error by adding the code found here to the handleError function.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41065984/phpmyadmin-mcrypt-error-on-php7-1#answer-41448260